# How to delete a constraint from sql server management studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I added a new column in one of my tables using the sql statement below:

```
ALTER TABLE DigitalResources ADD Ratings REAL DEFAULT 0.0;
```

This added the desired column into the table with all values set to NULL.

I then wanted to delete this column using the command below:

```
ALTER TABLE DigitalResources DROP COLUMN Ratings;
```

However, this generates the following error:

**Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The object 'DF__DigitalRe__Ratin__73852659' is dependent on column 'Ratings'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 11
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Ratings failed because one or more objects access this column.**

I even tried out the following commands to delete this constraint but to no avail:

```
DROP CONSTRAINT 'DF__DigitalRe__Rating__73852659';
ALTER TABLE DigitalResources DROP 'DF__DigitalRe__Rating__73852659';
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query

```
ALTER TABLE DigitalResources DROP DF_DigitalRe_Rating_73852659;
```

is correct. Remove the quotes around the constraint. It can be treated as an object rather than a value.